# Cannot await Task.Delay with .Net Core under Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, async-await

This very simple code does not work the same under Linux as it does on my Windows machine:

```
    class Program
    {
        async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                Console.WriteLine("" + i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Bye bye");
        }
    }
```

This should produce an output like

```
Hello World

0

1

.. 

4

Bye bye
```

It works well in development and if published to Windows. If published for Linux it hangs after putting out 'Hello World'. The await Task.Delay() never returns.

I've tried with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18 and CentOS 7. I've tried with ASP.Net Core 3.0 runtime  and 3.1 (also both fresh installations).

This code is only for demonstration purposes. Originally, I started to have problems when using a `System.Threading.Timer` in an ASP.Net BackgroundService (registered via services.AddHostedService()). The timer's callback there also didn't got called. That also happened only under Linux, whereas Windows works well.

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this problem?

**Update**
After the comment from Herohtar I've tested on a Windows subsystem Ubuntu. It is working there as well. 
Now I suspect the Linux image(s) of my hoster (virtual server at Strato.de) is somehow crippled.

Can someone think of a limitation in Linux that could cause such issues?

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce this problem. The code runs fine for me on Ubuntu 18.04.3 using the .NET Core 3.0 runtime.

Comment: Does `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false)` make a difference? It would if you are running on one CPU core and there is a SynchronizationContext involved.

Comment: Thanks for your idea Klaus! Sadly this doesn't make a visible difference. Still awaiting forever...

Comment: Timers on .net core on Linux are handled entirely by managed code (https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/TimerQueue.Portable.cs). The only thing I see that relies on the OS is `Environment.TickCount64`. I know that there can be clock issues on some virtualized environments, so that could be the culprit. Unfortunately it doesn't look like strato.de has free servers so I can't really dig further :/

Comment: What does `dotnet --info` print on your hosted Linux?

Comment: dotnet --info showed that I only had installed the runtimes: 

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  
To get more information I tried to install the SDK as well. To my surprise that installation also got stuck!

Comment: Can you do a simple test, like deploying a console app that runs `while (true) { Console.WriteLine(Environment.TickCount64); Thread.Sleep(1000); }` and see by how much the value increases in average

Comment: Sure. It runs and increases by 1000 like so 104352025
104353026
104354026

Comment: Then nothing is wrong with the clock. I'm out of leads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting response from Strato I can post the answer to my own question here: Strato is using Virtuozzo for their virtualization. For security reasons they have also disabled some features so that .Net core ist not running there.

For everyone else having the same problem: You can't use .Net core on Strato Linux V-Servers at all.

Thaks to everyone trying to help!